# Impala driver class not being found through Jaydebeapi Connection

Tags: java, python, jdbc, impala, jaydebeapi

I recently switched over from using a PC to a Mac and now for whatever reason one of my Impala drivers that worked fine is no longer found when run in Python. I keep receiving this error every time I run the script : "java.lang.RuntimeException: Class com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver not found". Please see code snippet for my connection below.

`c = jaydebeapi.connect
(jclassname='com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver',
url='jdbc:impala://cloudera-impala-proxy.live.bi.xxx/;AuthMech=3;ssl=1;',
driver_args=['xxx', self.dwh_password],                               jars='/Users/xxx/Desktop/ImpalaJDBC41 2.jar')`

Any help or suggestions are appreciated, I feel like I'm going crazy trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check do you have the ImpalaJDBC***.jar in your new machine.
Please check properly weather it's available at classpath/build path or not.

**Edit:**
You can use hive jdbc jar as well to connect with impala , just use the port of impala rather hive in jdbc url.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this error means your jar is corrupt.
First check your impalaJDBC jar

```
java -jar ImpalaJDBC<version>.jar
```

If it gives you error that means your jar is corrupt.

Download the correct jar from cloudera